# Deploying web api projects to appharbor from mvc beta fails

Tags: appharbor

When trying to deploy a new web api project which is created from the web api template it fails with the following message:

Build failed: Build contains no websites or background workers

Are mvc 4 web api project supported yet? Or do I have to create a regular MVC 3 app and include the web api stuff manually through nuget to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this was a stupid mistake by me but I'll keep the question here if someone run into the same issue. The problem was as simple as I forgot to turn on nuget package restore. Since I don't check in my packages I need to download them on install.